# Is there any way to access articles with restricted access (behind a paywall)?

Tags: discussion

When answering questions on this site, it is helpful to be able to read the primary literature.

Is there any legal way to access papers behind a paywall?

Can we add the best answer(s), or a pointer to them, to the FAQ?

Comment: While illegal in some regard, you can always ask other SE members to provide you with the pdf.

Comment: you can flag a moderator to tag this as a FAQ

Comment: @Abe I did flag a moderator but the flag was declined with the rationale: "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"

Comment: Okay. I will flag it again.

Comment: The FAQ tag is really meant for questions about the site itself, not for resources like this.

Comment: If anyone needs any pdf's I offer my services.

Comment: You guys have got to be kidding. SE is doing you a favor by letting you have a stack, don't play fools in their back sharing paid subscription content for free. If you want access to such resources, take a trip to your community college and use a computer, or _at least_ discuss such matters **outside** of this stack. Wouldn't want to put SE in trouble, now would you?

Comment: I don't want to be patronizing, but I feel like this is a sensitive subject.

Comment: @CHM I agree. If there are specific actions that you specifically think should be prohibited, please post an answer!

Answer (score 9):

I think my answer to a similar question at [parenting.se](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138/is-there-anything-we-can-do-to-get-better-access-to-research/139) may be useful:

Here are some options:

1. Search from [PubMed Central's](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/) free archive of journals (also try the [UK PubMed](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=N&tab=sw#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=Relationships+among+parenting+knowledge%2C+quality+of+stimulation+in+the+home+and+infant+development+filetype%3Apdf&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e8e7ddf4dbcd33f2))
2. [MayoClinic](http://www.mayoclinic.com/) has reputable summaries of medical research on its website
3. search google for the article title in quotes + filetype:pdf (see first link in [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Nuclear%20winter%3A%20global%20consequences%20of%20multiple%20nuclear%20explosions%22%20filetype%3Apdf&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=5d409e11edb055e4&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1080&bih=1834) example)
4. search google scholar, and when the article you want shows up, click the 'all N versions' link on the bottom right of the result - one may be in pdf format
5. Email the corresponding author and ask for a copy by pdf.
6. ask your librarian for help obtaining an article
7. write your congressperson and demand that federally funded research be made freely available

Comment: 5a. If the corresponding author does not respond, contact the first author: generally he/she made most of the work and should be more motivated to share his/her last results.

Answer (score 5):

Considering the fact that most of the SO.Biology users are either students or University employees (or both, like me :) ), it is often not a problem to get access to a certain publication -- the university library has a subscription which is available through your IP. PubMed and other search engines can detect your subscription and show you the paper availability directly in the search results.

Nonetheless, the chances that the person who asked the question or who found the thread using search engine doesn't have the same level of access to scientific publications is rather high. This is why I am trying to cite only those papers which are generally free and hence can be immediately linked from the answer. Often you find reviews not available, whereas single papers referenced by the review articles are.

Comment: the second point that you make is useful. Do you have evidence to support the first?

Comment: Strongly agree with finding free publications where possible

Comment: FWIW, I completely disagree that people should make the effort to cite only free papers. If we want expert answers, those answers should cite to the most relevant and useful resources. It's unfortunate that so much content is not free, and I support linking to free content when we can. If the best resource is not free, however, a free resource could be added as an auxiliary resource but *not* a substitute.

Answer (score 4):

As per a request by the inquirer,

I do not think that discussing of such matters as (most probably) illegal trade of paid subscription content is appropriate here.

There were good alternatives presented, which don't involve illegal actions.